# Dynamic List View with Text and Radio Button In Flutter

Tags: flutter

Unable to create dynamic list view with text and radio button in flutter

when i am creating  dynamically(Fetching the data from service and binding the data with text ) list view with text and radio button  when  i am selecting radio button it is not showing selected (indicator );

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class DemoTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
    theme: new ThemeData(
     primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
                   ),
      home: new DemoTestStatesFull(),
    );}}
class DemoTestStatesFull extends StatefulWidget {
  DemoTestState createState() => DemoTestState();
}

class DemoTestState extends State {
  final List<String> floor_list = [
    "floor1",
    "floor2",
    "floor3",
    "floor4",
    "floor5",
    "floor6",
  ];
  int _selectedIndex =0;
  int  _value2=0;
  Container datacontainer=new Container();

  _onSelected(int index) {
    setState(() => _selectedIndex = index);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Dynamic View Example'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Fetch Data"),
                onPressed:() {setState(() {
                    datacontainer= DisplayData(floor_list);//  Let Suppose  Here  getting data from web service after json parsing  string list is
                    print("Button is clicked");
                  });}),
            datacontainer,
     ],));}
  Widget  DisplayData(List<String>floorlist)
  {
    datacontainer   =new Container(
      height: 300.00,
      width: 400.00,
      child:  ListView.builder(
          itemCount: (floorlist.length),
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return new InkResponse(
                enableFeedback: true,
                onTap: ()
                {
                  print(" Card index is  $i");
                },
                child:new Card(
                    color: _selectedIndex != null && _selectedIndex == i ? Colors.greenAccent : Colors.white,
                    elevation: 3.0,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.00, 0.00, 5.00,5.00),
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.00,0.0, 0.0,0.0)),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: Text(floorlist[i], style: new 
TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          ),
                          Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70.00, 
                        0.0, 0.0,0.0)),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: Text(floorlist[i], style: new 
                             TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          ),
                          new Radio(
                            value: i,
                            groupValue: _value2,
                            onChanged:(int value)
                            {
                              setState(() {
                                _value2=value;
                                print("Radio index is  $value");
                             });}),])));}
      ),);return datacontainer;}}
```

just i want to create dynamic list view with text and select able radio button

Comment: Dimag khol diye bhai thanks a lot pskink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you can easily use gestureDetector for the row without the radio button and 
put radio button at trailing , listTile is like a row for the list and have title and trailing under it as a relative position inside the tile (listTile is the list row you want that contains text and a radio button) . 
ps : GestureDetector is a widget so you can return it instead of the left side of the row.

```
return ListTile(
          leading:GestureDetector(
                    child: //add the text here,
                    onTap: () { 
                      //here handle the onclick for text

                     } ,
           ) ,
          trailing://here add the radio button with onchanged normally,

                  );
```

hope that answers your question.